# React auth using useState for route

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying in a personal project
to learn react not to use redux only
hooks.
So I've got a simply custom hook

```
const useAuth = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  return { isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated };
};
```

to use for set the auth to true

but it doesn't work.

Here you can see an example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rky7dn?file=src%2Flogin.js

Can anyone tell me what's wrong please?

Comment: Custom hooks are used to encapsulate logic, not to share state, you have 2 independent `isAuthenticated` in 2 components, I made some changes to your code have a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gridw1?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined it right but using it wrong.
You want to do use the hook only once in your App.js and then pass down "setIsAuthenticated" to your Login.js (and not call the hook again)

```
//App.js
const { isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated } = useAuth();
...
<Route path="/login">{!isAuthenticated ? <Login setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated}/> : <Redirect from="/login" to="/" />}</Route>
```

```
//Login.js
const Login = ({setIsAuthenticated}) => {
....
```